# fixture is_udp not found (although it is declared a few lines before)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest, fixtures

This is my code (fixtures for conftest):

```
@pytest.fixture
def is_udp(request):
    yield request.config.getoption('--target') == 'udp'

.
.
.

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def foo(request, is_udp):
    if not is_udp:
        return True
```

My error is this:

```
E       fixture 'is_udp' not found
available fixtures: __pytest_repeat_step_number, allocator_files, bu_test_max_iters, cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, cov, debug_target, doctest_namespace, estimator_files, foo, max_batches, memory_analyze, metadata, monke
ypatch, no_cover, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

Is the `autouse=True` causes a mismatch in the fixtures pytest can see?

After removing this fixture from `foo` (I have another way to get the info I need), I get the same error in another fixture that is also trying to use `is_udp`. After removing this one I get the same error for another fixture. Both of fixtures are defined, and have no other objects that can shadow them.

Comment: Can't reproduce on my machine; please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a bad import (I actually had 2 files and even though all fixtures were on the same one,they were actually called from another file who knew only part of them)

This is waht really happend:

```
File A:
fixture foo
fixture goo(foo) (autouse=True)
*Makes me think goo should know foo as they are in the same file*

File B:
from ... import goo
# no import for foo
# using goo because it is autouse and failing because it doesn't know foo
```

Fixed by adding an import for foo in File B